# which data type correspond to 10^16 in C++?

Tags: c++, types, algebraic-data-types

My C++ programme may create a value until 10^16 during the run time, I tried to use "long long int" for it but it didn't work. Which data type correspond to 10^16?

Thanks;

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it didn't work" please?

Comment: there is no answer in my programme for 6 minutes, when i finished my programme i saw overflow error.

Comment: @Selen That sounds more like a stack overflow than an integer overflow. What makes you think the `10^16` value is the problem?

Comment: That doesn't tell me much, since I don't know what your program consists of.  Try this: `long long x = 10000000000000000; std::cout << x;` -- If that works, then your problem is elsewhere.  If it doesn't work, then your compiler is broken.

Comment: my programme should support L(n)=(12+12)(12+22)(12+32) ..(12+n2) (22+22)(22+32) .. (22+n2) (32+32)(32+42)...(32+n2) .....(n2+n2) fonction for three input. One of them is n and it's range should be  like this 1≤ n ≤10^8. when i write long long x = 1000000000000000 , it works but when i run my programme for n = 100000000 , i get an error that is 'process terminated with status -1073741510'

Comment: Clearly your problem then is not that `long long int` does not hold 10^16.  It is somewhere in the logic of your program, which we can't see.  So this question is answered.  You should accept an answer and ask a new question about your code and what is wrong with it.

Comment: I will rewiew my code again. I think there is stg wrong. Thanks for all your anwers.

Comment: If you are multiplying this sized long long values, they will overflow.

Answer (score 6):

The minimum guaranteed maximum of `long long int` is `2^63 - 1`, which is approximately `10^19`. It should be fine. To be sure, use the `std::int_least64_t` type from `<cstdint>`. It is guaranteed to have at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

less than 64bit so.. long long should be good..

Comment: This should probably be a comment unless you can expand a bit on it.

Comment: i tried long long but it didnt work i think that problem is about compiler, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try `int64_t`. That should be long enough. But be sure to enter an integer literal:

```
int64_t n = 10000000000000000;
```

If you say `1E16`, that's a `double` literal, and the conversion to integer may produce unexpected results.

Comment: 10000000000000000LL <- the suffix might be required for some compilers.

Comment: Unless you're running your gcc in pre-C99 mode, which seems you are by default, (or if it's simply some C89/90 compiler) and the compiler truncates what would've been a normal long long constant in C99 to the longest integer type supported by C89, which is long (or unsigned long). Surprise.

Answer (score -2):

Unsigned long long Int works up-to 10^18!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.